# Save restore object in memory for later debugging - visual studio

Tags: .net, debugging

This is a general debugging question. Often you find yourself debugging a particular method where the input types might be strong types.

I am looking for a generic visual studio plugin that can save strongly typed objects and then restore them later in another debug session.

I'm using a fairly old version of visual studio 2008, without this plugin I was thinking of writing a serialize object to xml -> deserialize from xml routine.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: how about a utility method that can serialize (binary) any object that you can call from the Immediate window that writes the serialized bytes to a file ? You can then read this file from a unit test or other place where required. Is this what you meant by `restore them later in another debug session`? ps: i would stay away from the xml serializer